# Take the input fields from comboBox and then join both the fields with some expression and store the result in the newly added field

Tags: qgis, expression, combo-box

I am trying to take two fields as input fields from QgsFieldComboBox and then I want to join the fields and store the result in another field (to the same layer). I am using QGIS version 3. I want to do this with a custom plugin.

This is my code

```
def join_fields(self):
    if self.dlg.Field1_ComboBox.currentText() == self.dlg.Field2_ComboBox.currentText():
        self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage(
            "Error","Please select different fields in both the combobox",
            level = Qgis.Critical, duration=3
            )
        
    layer = self.dlg.cb_layer.currentLayer()

    
    
    output = self.dlg.output_field.text()
    
    
    Field1 = self.dlg.Field1_ComboBox.currentText()
    Field2 = self.dlg.Field2_ComboBox.currentText()
    
   
    
    layer.startEditing()
```

#so basically i am getting my error in writing an expression . I am doing it via plugin. Can somebody tell me how to write an expression by giving the fields as parameters from combo boxes. I am unable to do it.

```
    e = QgsExpression ('"Field1"+"Field2"' )
    context = QgsExpressionContext()
    context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        f[output] = e.evaluate(context)
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

[image: As soon as plugin is loaded]

[image: After selecting/clicking on a layer , the fields in select field1/field2 are loaded]

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question to indicate what error or other incorrect result is generated by your code (a problem statement).

Comment: I have edited the body. please look into it amnd tell me how to write an expression and evaluate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use some kind of string formatting to insert the string values which are stored in your `Field1` and `Field2` variables into your expression string instead of the variable names as string literals, which is what you are doing now.

You have not said what data type are your fields. If your fields are numeric and you are trying to arithmetically add the 2 field values together, you can do something like:

```py
Field1 = self.dlg.Field1_ComboBox.currentField()
Field2 = self.dlg.Field2_ComboBox.currentField()
    
e = QgsExpression (f'"{Field1}"+"{Field2}"' )
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    context.setFeature(f)
    f[output] = e.evaluate(context)
    layer.updateFeature(f)
```

If your fields contain string values which you are trying to concatenate together, you probably want to change the expression to something like:

```py
e = QgsExpression (f'concat("{Field1}", \' \', "{Field2}")')
```

---

Edit- not related to original question but in response to comment:

I do not know what your plugin structure looks like, but essentially, you need to set the parent layer for both of your field combo boxes when your `self.dlg` object is initialized and set both of their indexes to 0. You also need to do this every time the layer in the combo box changes. I recommend doing this with a slot method which is connected to the `layerChanged` signal of your `QgsMapLayerComboBox`.

You should make sure this signal slot connection is only made once, when the plugin is initialized. I don't use Plugin Builder, so I always create the `self.dlg` object in the `__init__()` method of the main plugin class then set up signal/slot connections in the `initGui()` method.

However, if you have used Plugin Builder, you would probably have something like this:

```py
def run(self):
    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
    # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False
        self.dlg = YourPluginDialog()
        # Make sure you have these lines...
        self.dlg.Field1_ComboBox.setLayer(self.dlg.cb_layer.currentLayer())
        self.dlg.Field2_ComboBox.setLayer(self.dlg.cb_layer.currentLayer())
        self.dlg.Field1_ComboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.dlg.Field2_ComboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.dlg.cb_layer.layerChanged.connect(self.cb_layer_changed)

def cb_layer_changed(self, lyr):
    '''Method which is triggered when the current layer in self.dlg.cb_layer is changed'''
    self.dlg.Field1_ComboBox.setLayer(lyr)
    self.dlg.Field2_ComboBox.setLayer(lyr)
    self.dlg.Field1_ComboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)
    self.dlg.Field2_ComboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)
```

Here is a very minimal example program which you can run in the Python console which should show you exactly how this works:

```py
class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(350, 350, 500, 250)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.cb_layer = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self)
        self.Field1_ComboBox = QgsFieldComboBox(self)
        self.Field2_ComboBox = QgsFieldComboBox(self)
        self.Field1_ComboBox.setLayer(self.cb_layer.currentLayer())
        self.Field2_ComboBox.setLayer(self.cb_layer.currentLayer())
        self.Field1_ComboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.Field2_ComboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.btn = QPushButton('OK', self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cb_layer)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.Field1_ComboBox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.Field2_ComboBox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.cb_layer.layerChanged.connect(self.layer_changed)

        
    def layer_changed(self, lyr):
        self.Field1_ComboBox.setLayer(lyr)
        self.Field2_ComboBox.setLayer(lyr)
        self.Field1_ComboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.Field2_ComboBox.setCurrentIndex(0)


dlg = MyDialog()
dlg.show()
```

The resulting behavior looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you , this worked for me!!!

Comment: @sahilk, that's great- you're welcome.

Comment: Also , i have attached the plugin photo in the body, When i run the plugin ,as you can see in the image above the field1/field2 fields are not getting loaded. they load once you go on the select layer combo box & click/select one layer . then only the fields get loaded so what can i do to load the fields of selected layer as soon as the plugin is run.

Comment: @sahilk, I have edited my question. I have tried to answer your query as best as I can, but not knowing your plugin structure makes it difficult. In future, you should really ask a new question and include your relevant plugin code to make it easier for people to try and help you.

Comment: Thank You , It worked.